# The application is running fine when executed from the IDE Visual Studio but doesn't display a report when executed .exe file from the debug folder

Tags: vb.net

There was a little problem in the code which I corrected and now the system runs fine when compiled and executed from the IDE Visual Studio. But the problem is when I run the application from the debug folder or lets say the published or installed application doesn't reflect the corrections I made even after rebuilding and cleaning the solution. In-short, the debug folder has the application with the previous mistakes which I already corrected. What might be the reasons?

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you built it using the `Release` profile?

Comment: It is awfully vague without a repro snippet.  But the standard bug is relying too much on Environment.CurrentDirectory.  When running from the IDE it is set to the project directory, so any "report" that you forgot to copy/deploy can be found.  Not when running it directly, then it is set to the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: "then it is set to the same directory as the EXE"'. The report can be found in the directory but its not updated to reflect the changes I made

Comment: @Jimi No, I built in the debug profile